# UISegmentedControl backgroundImageForState not returning my image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, uiappearance

I'm using `UIApperance` to set background images within my `UISegmentedControl`, like so:

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:normalBackgroundImage
                                           forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                         barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:selectedBackgroundImage 
                                           forState:UIControlStateSelected 
                                         barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

My images are taller than the standard `UISegmentedControl` sizes, however.  So later, I'm attempting to get a control's background images so I can resize the control, like so:

```
UIImage *imageForHeight = [self.segmentedControl 
                                backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal 
                                             barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This method call returns `nil`, and I can't for the life figure out why.  The control is actually using the images that I put in `UIAppearance`.  Does anyone know why this method isn't returning my images, or a different way to get the background image back out of the segmented control?

Answer (score 0):

You set images on appearance proxy, but trying to get it from an instance. Try setting images on instance itself and it should work.

If you need to use proxy (say more than 1 control), I would recommend computing image sizes beforehand and adjusting frame.

Comment: That's basically the approach I went with, but it's ugly.  I have code  setting images in one place (the UIAppearance proxy) and code in another place to size the image that has to find the same image somehow.  It's exactly what I was trying to avoid and feel like I shouldn't have to do.